# Handling "Accept Cookies" popup with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, alert

I've been trying to scrape some information of this real estate website with selenium. However when I access the website I need to accept cookies to continue. This only happens when the bot accesses the website, not when I do it manually. When I try to find the corresponding element either by xpath or id, as I find it when I inspect the page manually I get following error.

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="uc-btn-accept-banner"]"}

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



PATH = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.immoweb.be/en/search/house/for-sale?countries=BE&page=1&orderBy=relevance")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="uc-btn-accept-banner"]').click()
```

Does anyone know how to get around this? Why can't I find the element?

Below is an image of the accept cookies popup.

[image]

This is the HTML corresponding to the button "Keep browsing". The XPATH is as above.

```
<button aria-label="Keep browsing" id="uc-btn-accept-banner" class="uc-btn-new  uc-btn-accept">Keep browsing
          <span id="uc-optin-timer-display"></span></button>
```

Comment: Is the popup really an alert? Or is it elements in the DOM that are made visible and positioned withe some combination of JavaScript and CSS?

Comment: Interesting point, I think you could be onto something, however when I look for the matching elements by id within my window I can't find them. As a result I thought they must be in a different window. How would I then approach this issue?

Comment: Can you show the popup? I opened the site and I didn't get any popups (I waited for more than 1 minute)

Comment: My suggestion to debug this is to first be sure your selenium driver is not running headless. Then use your favorite debugger to set a breakpoint after your `driver.get()` call. Now you can inspect the page directly in Chrome to discover how to access the popup.

Comment: You don't need to switch. What you see is a modal. Just click the button. If you remove the `alert = driver.switch_to.alert` part, your code works.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I had tried this before. I will edit my question and describe the problem as it is now, would be great to get some more feedback please.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You were very close!

If you open your page in a new  browser you'll note the page fully loads, then, a moment later your popup appears.

The default wait strategy in selenium is just that [the page is loaded](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/page_loading_strategy/). That draw delay between page loaded and display appearing is causing your scripts to fail.

You have two good synchronisation options.

1/
Include an implicit wait for your driver. This is done once per script and affects all objects. This waits 10 seconds before throwing any error, or continues when it's ready:

```
PATH = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get("https://www.immoweb.be/en/search/house/for-sale?countries=BE&page=1&orderBy=relevance")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="uc-btn-accept-banner"]').click()
```

2/
Do a explicit wait on your object only:

```
PATH = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.immoweb.be/en/search/house/for-sale?countries=BE&page=1&orderBy=relevance")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="uc-btn-accept-banner"]'))).click()
```

More info on the wait strategies is [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)