# Selenium can't locate element

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I'm using selenium and I have a problem handling the accept cookies pop-up.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

web = webdriver.Chrome("C:/chromedriver")
web.get('https://www.spaargids.be/sparen/schuldsaldo-berekenen.html')

time.sleep(2)

akkoord = web.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[3]/button[1]')
```

When I inspect the element, I can easily find it. But selenium is unable to do it.
Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64032271/handling-accept-cookies-popup-with-selenium-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the element is inside an iframe, you need to switch to the respective iframe.

Try this before akkoord variable:

```
web.switch_to.frame(web.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@title="SP Consent Message"]'))
```

That should make it work, then use the same approach but updating the XPATH to switch to the iframe where the content is.