# How to click cookies pop up window with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click 'akceptuj wszystkie' button in facebook:
[screenshot of window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqBKn.png)

I tried to click it by actions but there is error unable to locate alement:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"._42ft _4jy0 _9o-t _4jy3 _4jy1 selected _51sy"}
```

I tried by switch to window but there is error:
`driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1]) IndexError: list index out of range`

how can I click this button, any ideas?

Comment: `driver.switch_to_window` won't work because the cookies popup is not a window.

Comment: See this: [handling-accept-cookies-popup-with-selenium-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64032271/handling-accept-cookies-popup-with-selenium-in-python). Also see this: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like that pop-up is not an iframe or window. Please try below code.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div._4t2a button[data-cookiebanner='accept_button']").click()
```

edit : quotes fixed

Comment: You probably need some escaping there (because of the single quotes)

Comment: Use double quotes for the string: `"div._4t2a button[data-cookiebanner='accept_button']"`