# How can i eliminate the "accept cookies" popup that blocking the content of webpage?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, popup

I already spend a week trying to figure out how to dismiss the "accept cookies" popup that keeps freezing my code. I borrowed the code from [here](https://python.plainenglish.io/how-to-build-a-football-dataset-with-web-scraping-d4deffcaa9ca?gi=fdec9b046a61) and transformed it a bit to meet my needs. I searched the site but almost nothing to seem like my case. I m posting the portion of the code that causes the problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.opera.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

errors = []
season = []


for id in range(2124889, 2124890):
# Opening the connection and grabbing the page
my_url = f'https://www.lefigaro.fr/sports/football/live/bundesliga/2020/{id}/*'
option = Options()
option.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Opera(options=option)
driver.get(my_url)
driver.maximize_window()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((
        By.XPATH,'//iframe[@id="appconsent"]')))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((
        By.XPATH,'//button[contains(@title,"Tout Accepter")]'))).click()
sleep(5)
```

Comment: Please check this thread out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64032271/handling-accept-cookies-popup-with-selenium-in-python

Comment: How often do you get the accept cookies pop up ?

Comment: @cruisepandey every new driver.get that opens the browser. Solution from Prophet worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```py
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((
        By.XPATH,'//iframe[@id="appconsent"]')))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((
        By.XPATH,'//button[contains(@title,"Tout Accepter")]'))).click()
```

Use this

```py
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((
        By.XPATH,"//div[@id='appconsent']//iframe")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((
        By.CSS_SELECTOR,'button.button__acceptAll'))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create an UI handle for cookies popup, you can set an argument at browser's option level:

```
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies": 2})
```