# Selenium Edge Webdriver Notification Disable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver, microsoft-edge

When Selenium opens the Edge WebDriver, there are few notifications popup, which break my code when the code try to click on a button on the website (I think the notification goes on top of the website, so the code cannot find the button it supposed to get). Is there a way to disable all the notifications? I use Python. Here are the three notifications:

[Personalized_Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HydF5.png)

[Profile_Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFH16.png)

[Cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvPCe.png)

GPT suggested to open the Edge WebDriver in private mode. The code runs, but the WebDriver did not open in a private mode:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options

edge_options = Options()

edge_options.add_argument("ms:inPrivate")

driver = webdriver.Edge(options=edge_options)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to turn off `Show feature and workflow recommendations` by configuring browser flags. Something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge import service

edgeOption = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
edgeOption.use_chromium = True
edgeOption.add_argument("start-maximized")
edgeOption.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
edgeOption.add_argument("--disable-features=msEdgeEnableNurturingFramework")
edgeOption.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"user_experience_metrics": {"personalization_data_consent_enabled": True}})
edgeOption.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
s=service.Service(r'D:\EdgeDriver\119.0.2151.97\msedgedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=s, options=edgeOption)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Regarding the cookie acceptance popup you mentioned, it seems to me that they are located in different frames, and you need to use different ways to find the element located in the page and then handle it(accept or close). like this:[Handling "Accept Cookies" popup with Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64032271/handling-accept-cookies-popup-with-selenium-in-python)

Comment: Thank you Xudong. The code disabled the personalization notification, but not the log in profile popup. However, I decided to use Chrome WedDriver instead, it does not pop up any of these notifications. The only thing I need to deal with Chrome Driver is the Cookies acceptance popup, which come with the website itself.

Comment: Well, this is your choice. By the way, can this problem be solved if you specify a profile? Like this: `edgeOption.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data");
edgeOption.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 2");`